# Summing up the total abundance for each type of element of a column in a table

Tags: python, data-science

I don't really know how to phrase this so I hope it will be understandable.
I have a large csv file which contains thousands of rows and several columns, that's basically like this :

| Class | DBE | Abundance | H/C | N/C | O/C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class 1 | 1 | 10000 | 0.9 | 0.08 | 0.8 |
| Class 1 | 2 | 50000 | 0.8 | 0.08 | 0.6 |
| Class 2 | 1 | 20000 | 0.9 | 0.06 | 0.5 |
| Class 2 | 1 | 30000 | 0.8 | 0.08 | 0.8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

...

I want to get the total abundance for every same class (so sum up all the abundances of class 1, class 2, etc.) and of every same DBE. I also want the total abundance for a set of (H/C, N/C) and for the set (H/C, O/C). I began to this manually but it's very long, so I was hoping to use python, as I know a little of it and it seems to have libraries for calculations. What would be the best way to achieve this? This histogram function in numpy seems interesting but requires to know the "bins". Coding something to scroll through the table seems overkill.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the `pandas` library and its `groupby` function?

Comment: `totals = df.groupby(["Class"]).sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is hihly appreciated if you share your (non functional) code and not just the task you want to sovle, see the guidelines for this.

To your question:
You could try to use the [pandas groupby function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) after reading the csv file to an pandas dataframe.

for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file")
df.groupby(["Class"].sum())
```

Then you sum up all columns, besides Class, where you are grouping after and should have your solution.

Comment: I didn't know where to start, so I had no code to propose. I was asking for guidelines. 

groupby function is what I was looking for, I didn't know about it and it's pretty powerful and simple to use.